# mysql inner join two tables with int and enum data type

Tags: mysql

How to join two table table with different data types?
in the first table status field type is enum and in second table it is int, how i can join these tables

Comment: Could you give an example of what the tables look like? (schemas/contents)

Comment: Really it should just be an INT in both columns.  Normally an ENUM would be used for storing strings where there are only specific strings used.

Comment: Just try the with joins on those columns and see if there is any issue. ENUM values are anyways integer and so should not be a issue joining them with a int field (That's a Guess though).

Answer (score 1):

Enum type is stored by MySQL as an int, so you can do the join as usual. But in case both fields were different you should cast one of them to make their types match if possible (usually with cast functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)